# Why can I not call add() on a tab after finding it by ID in extjs?

Tags: extjs

Why can I not call "add" on a tab after finding by ID in extjs?

```
var tabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
    id:'maintabs',
    activeTab:0,
    layoutOnTabChange:true,
    deferredRender:false
 });
 var tab = {
   title:'testing',
   html:'testing'
 } 

 I can see in my chrome console that tabPanel here has the method "add", and I can add this tab to the tab panel...
```

However, when I define my tab in a viewport like so...

```
initComponent: function(){
    Ext.apply(this, {
        layout: {
          type: 'fit'
        },
          items: [
          {
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            id:'maintabs',
            layoutOnTabChange:true,
            deferredRender:false,
            activeTab: 0, // index or id
            items:[...
```

However, considering the following:

```
Ext.get('maintabs').add(tab);
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'add'
```

What gives here? Why is there no method 'add'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different between `get` and `getCmp`. `get()` returns you a wrapper around a DOM element. `getCmp()` returns you an Ext.Component (or subclass).